# Img Animation with Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, image, slideshow, settimeout

Why the timeout don't work?
If i work without the function sleep, they return to me an undefined data..
With this function they work but without sleeping time, they go directly to the last image.. :-/

```
    function sleep(value, data, i) {
        document.getElementById(value).src = data[i];
    }

function imgAnimation(value){
    var img = document.getElementById(value).src;
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "static/cercaThumbs.php",
    data: 'id=' + value,
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var elements = Object.keys(data).length;
        for (var i = 0; i < elements; i++) {
                if(i == elements){i = 0;}
                setTimeout(sleep(value, data, i), 300);
        }
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a function to `setTimeout`. You're *calling* the function `sleep` and passing its *result*.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  sleep(value, data, i);
}, 300);
```

But it still won't work, because you're setting a bunch of timeouts at the same time, so they'll all trigger 300ms later at the same time. To animate you might try something like:

```js
var data = [
  'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.2/assets/png/0030.png',
  'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.2/assets/png/0031.png',
  'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.2.2/assets/png/0032.png',
]
var frame = 0;
var elements = data.length;
var animation = setInterval(function() {
  frame = (frame + 1) % elements;
  document.getElementById('test').src = data[frame];
}, 300);
```

```html
<img id=test>
```

This sets up a single repeating callback which can advance to the next frame each time. In the example above it will loop forever, or you can call `clearInterval(animation)` once you're finished.

Comment: But the setTimeout is in the cycle.. You can take an example..?

Comment: The important thing to remember is that setTimeout returns _immediately_. It won't sleep for 300ms. So they will all queue up at the same time.

Comment: I've turned it into a runnable snippet to show it in action.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, with the help of Nick, this is the correct code:

```
function imgAnimation(value){
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "static/cercaThumbs.php",
    data: 'id=' + value,
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        var elements = Object.keys(data).length;
        var frame = 0;
        var animation = setInterval(function() {
        frame = (frame + 1) % elements;
        document.getElementById(value).src = data[frame];
        }, 500);
        document.getElementById(value).addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
            clearInterval(animation);
            document.getElementById(value).src = data['0'];
        });
    }
    });
}
```